# What package I can use to generate a Run Chart?

Tags: r, plot, charts

I am going to generate a Run Chart in `R`. I need a package and example to show me how to do this. I found the `"qicharts"` package but apparently is has a problem to install.

Comment: A run chart is a time series or a line plot mostly, you can do that with base ploting or ggplot easily

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what kind pf Problem do you have while installing `"qicharts"`? Do you get an error? I am asking because it is working for me.

Nevertheless you might also want to have a lock at the `"qcc"`-Package. [Here](http://www.stat.unipg.it/luca/Rnews_2004-1-pag11-17.pdf) you can find something like a small introduction and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qcc/qcc.pdf) is the cran help to the package.

But I also think that the chance is high that you can plot your with `"ggplot2"` too.

Comment: Thanks it was a mistake from my side that I got error for qicharts!